# GCP Container Scanning not triggered by pushing to Artifact Repository

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, containers

Even though the Container Scanning API is enabled and Vulnerability scanning is enabled for the Artifact Registry, newly pushed images are not being scanned.

[image]

On-demand scan results also don't show up in the Artifact Repository UI.

[image]

Is there something else I need to enable?

Answer (score 4):

I believe your containers are being pushed to Google Container Registry (GCR), as evident by "Container Registry host" being `eu.gcr.io` in your first screenshot. The results should be available in the GCR page and won't show up in  the Artifact Registry page.

On-demand scans are not accessible through the UI (Artifact Registry or GCR pages). You can only access the results through the `gcloud` CLI: https://cloud.google.com/container-analysis/docs/on-demand-scanning-howto#retrieve

Comment: Hi Yousef, thanks for your answer. I am in fact using the Artifact Registry, however as part of the Container Registry transition, our Artifact Repositories are forwarded to GCR. Images being pushed to Artifact Repo are only showing up there, though - not in GCR.
I was able to make it work in a different project without this transition configuration, so it must be connected to this. Could you maybe provide more insight if this is a known limitation/bug?

Comment: Also thanks for the heads-up about On-Demand scans not showing up in the UI, that was very helpful.

Comment: I'm a little confused, the transition should be FROM GCR to AR. I don't recall a method to transition the other way. Is that first screenshot from the GCR or AR page? And can you provide the container's tag that you'r using to push?